Fetch and display images from Kirby blocks field through KQL
Hi there I am using Kirby as a backend for a Nuxt site. To do that I am fetching the data from Kirby through the plug-in Nuxt KQL (https://github.com/johannschopplich/nuxt-kql). I managed fetching all of the textual data but I couldn’t find a way to fetch from KQL images. In particular I have single files fields as well as files fields nested in structure fields.
This is the Kirby blocks YML:
casecontentblocks:
label: Content
type: blocks
fieldsets:
  textblock:
    name: Text (1 column)
    label: Text (1 column)
    fields:
      blocktitle:
        label: Title
        type: text
      paragraph:
        name: Text
        label: Text
        type: textarea
        headings:
          - 3
  imageblock:
    name: Image
    label: Image
    fields:
      image:
        label: Image
        type: files
        max: 1
        width: 1/2
      caption:
        name: Caption
        label: Caption
        type: textarea
        width: 1/2
  doubletextblock:
    name: Text (2 columns)
    label: Text (2 columns)
    fields:
      blocktitle:
        label: Title
        type: text
      paragraphleft:
        name: Text (left)
        label: Text (left)
        type: textarea
        width: 1/2
        headings:
          - 3
      paragraphright:
        name: Text (right)
        label: Text (right)
        type: textarea
        width: 1/2
        headings:
          - 3
  doubleimageblock:
    name: Double image
    label: Double image
    fields:
      imageleft:
        label: Image (left)
        type: files
        max: 1
        width: 1/2
      captionleft:
        name: Caption (left)
        label: Caption (left)
        type: textarea
        width: 1/2
      imageright:
        label: Image (right)
        type: files
        width: 1/2
        max: 1
      captionright:
        name: Caption (right)
        label: Caption (right)
        type: textarea
        width: 1/2
  imagesblock:
    name: Images
    label: Images
    fields:
      imagesblockimages:
        label: Images
        type: structure
        fields:
          imagesblockimagesimage:
            label: Image
            type: files
            max: 1
          imagesblockimagescaption:
            name: Caption
            label: Caption
            type: textarea
  spacerblock:
    name: Spacer
    label: Spacer

This is how I am displaying the fetched data in the .ts file:
casecontentblocks: { query: 'page.casecontentblocks.toBlocks' },

And this is how I am trying to display the images in the .vue template:
<div v-for="block in page?.casecontentblocks" :key="block.id" class="single-module">
        <div v-if="block.type === 'textblock'" class="module-text-one-column">
          <!-- textual block not needed here -->
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="block.type === 'imageblock'" class="module-image">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-12"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-12">
              <img :src="page?.casecontentblocksimage.find(b => b.id === block.id).image.url" alt="Image" />
              <div class="caption">
                <span v-html="block.content.caption"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="block.type === 'doubletextblock'" class="module-text-two-columns">
         <!-- textual block not needed here -->
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="block.type === 'doubleimageblock'" class="module-double-image">
          <img :src="block.content.imageleft.url" />
          <img :src="block.content.imageright.url" />
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="block.type === 'imagesblock'" class="module-images">
          <div v-for="blockimages in block.content.imagesblockimages" :key="blockimages.id" class="single-image">
            <img :src="blockimages.image.url" alt="Image" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="block.type === 'spacerblock'" class="module-spacer"></div>
      </div>

Do you have any clue about how images urls inside Kirby blocks field should be queried? Especially when they are inside structure fields?
Thanks for any help!
